# URL of Email Threads on Gmail Mobile App

Tags: gmail

What's the URL format of an email thread within a Gmail application? I have a list of email topics that I want to link to their respective threads. When I use the URL format as seen from my laptop (e.g., `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/[ID]`) and I try to open that URL from Gmail app, it opens in a browser instead of the Gmail app. Changing it to m.gmail.com doesn't seem to work as well.